# Error 404 when receive POST

Tags: php, json, post

I need send a json POST from android to web server with php. I try a lot of codes but don't works.

Now I try a simply POST with Postman, with and without send data. And always receive a 404 error. If I send data with GET the page work fine.

See the php, for if you want to test:

web: http://gclimb.com/Androidphp/index.php

```
<?php
$json  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj["username"];
echo $obj["pass"];

if ($_POST["username"]) {
echo $_POST["username"];
}
if ($_GET["username"]) {
echo $_GET["username"];
}

 ?>
```

**EDIT**

[POSTMAN screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7JXx.jpg)

404 Error:

POST /androidphp/index.php HTTP/1.1 Host: gclimb.com Cache-Control: no-cache Postman-Token: de575030-0343-64d9-fce3-e640ce12780c Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW ---- Get 404 error

Work fine:

GET /androidphp/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: gclimb.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f2999796-9338-6ef6-9877-075be9a8e530

Comment: For me postman returns always correct value... either in POST and GET.

Comment: replace $obj["username"] with '$obj -> username' and try again .

Comment: @RaV, really?? I only select POST type, and add url, and return 404 error -_-' the same with: gclimb.com/androidphp/index.php?username=Myname (POST type)

Comment: Both work for me while using POST with Postman.

Comment: @Bikash P I change code, but get a 404 error. this is my sended json data with Postman: {
"username":"myname",
"pass":"12345"
}

Comment: Rally? Why? How it's posible?

Comment: Dunno. Its something wrong with your configuration tho. I am getting now only code of page, some scripts, no content.

Comment: POST /androidphp/index.php?username=myname&pass=12345 HTTP/1.1
Host: gclimb.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3592da6e-c8ff-8f83-bb75-ee08635e8229
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Comment: Please see the EDIT of post

Comment: @Cofeina If you POST to `/Androidphp/index.php` instead of `/androidphp/index.php`, does it work for you? It does for me. Something seems to be re-writing your GET request to use the appropriate upper-casing, but not re-writing your POST request similarly.

Comment: @Patrick, ok... the problem is with the upper A.. -_- Androidphp works... but why get works with lower case? or why don't work post?

Comment: POST doesn't work because paths are case-sensitive (unless hosted on a Windows box). There is no file `/androidphp/index.php`.  I can't answer why GET is working because I don't know the specific settings/configurations running on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I will provide a complete PHP and an android Application to send data from android application to server.

Suppose you have this table in your database:

```
------------------------
| movie_id | movie_name|
------------------------
```

**1- PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php 
 $servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db="derar";
$connection=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$db);
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$movie_name=$obj['movie_name'];
mysqli_query($connection,"insert into  movie (movie_id, movie_name) VALUES (NULL,'$movie_name');");
echo "inserted";
?>
```

this code is simple code, you have to put a SQL injection.

**2-Android Application**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.win7.derar.MainActivity">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/send_button"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:text="إضغط لإرسال المعلومات"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  Button send_button;
    private String Server_URL="http://192.168.1.101/derar/insertDataToServer.php";
    private String movie_name="Titanic";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        send_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);// Button Assignment
        send_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendDataToServer sendDataToServer=new SendDataToServer();
                sendDataToServer.execute(Server_URL,movie_name);


            }
        });// Button On Click Listener
    }


    private class SendDataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

            OutputStream os = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;


            try {

                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("movie_name", urls[1]);
                String message = jsonObject.toString();
                Log.d(message, "Test");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

                conn.connect();

                os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                os.write(message.getBytes());

                os.flush();

                is = conn.getInputStream();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ;
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ;
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                try {
                    assert os != null;
                    os.close();
                    assert is != null;
                    is.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                conn.disconnect();
            }


            return true;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result) {


                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "لقد نجح إرسال المعلومات", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "فشل في إرسال المعلومات", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to do :

1-  add this permission to manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2- Change the IP address from this `Server_URL="http://192.168.1.101/derar/insertDataToServer.php";`

to your own IP address in order to run the localhost server.

I hope this would be useful to you.

Comment: A lot of thanks @SubhiMMM !! Work perfectly. How do you do to get the php response? ("echo "inserted";").

Comment: Please give more details about ( How to get the php response ? ).

Answer (score 0):

When making a `POST request`, don't forget that the request path is *case-sensitive*!

Try out to perform your request with this target:

```
http://gclimb.com/androidphp/index.php
```